# How to hide TD in Html

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
    <tr height="50" style="background-color:#d5d5d5; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; font-size:15px;">
        <td border="0" width="20%">Bölge</td>
        <td width="10%">Memur</td>
        <td width="10%">Söz.Memur</td>
        <td width="1%" class="weekly" id="1" visibility= "hidden" style="display:none;"></td>
        <td width="10%">Kad.İşci</td>
    </tr>
```

ı want id="1" td field hide . ı use in export html this table. so ı want hidden it .

Comment: `style="display:none;"` would normally work for hiding an element. Can you please describe how exactly the above code is not working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Using a Javascript you can do `document.getElementById("1").style.display = "none";`. Though your *question* is a bit unclear.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function HideIt() {
            console.log("hi");
            document.getElementById("1").style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="HideIt();">click to hide</button>
    <table>
        <tr height="50" style="background-color:#d5d5d5; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; font-size:15px;">
            <td border="0" width="20%">Bölge</td>
            <td width="10%">Memur</td>
            <td width="10%">Söz.Memur</td>
            <td width="1%" class="weekly" id="1"></td>
            <td width="10%">Kad.İşci</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But bro this export html page not use any button you can use button in code but need auto set and hide it.

Comment: @LakerOps, the snippet uses a button to hide it. How you implement the functionality is up to you. I just merely showed you what does it `.style.display = "none"` which is pretty much equivalent to the `style="display:none;"` you are already doing.

Comment: not working style display:none bro . maybe problem ı use this html website convert pdf so javascript and style display:none not effect it. When click export button this html running and convert action pdf and downloading pdf file .